# How to wrap the Image::Magick to PAR(perl)?

Tags: perl

ImageMagick Download
[http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16
in ALL Dll copy
*.dll

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $l;
my @dll=glob "*.dll";
$l.=" -l $_" foreach(@dll);
#print $l;
print `pp -v -o ss.exe$l img.pl`;
```

run image.exe
**SUCESS!!!!**

## I also try gm.exe
thanks people

=================================================================================

**image.exe(double-click) completion does not create k.jpg

Please tell me how to solve**
perl pp.pl  -> create "image.exe"

perl image.pl -> create k.jpg
image.exe(Double-click) -> can't create k.jpg

image.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::Magick;
my $img=Image::Magick->new;
$img->Read('s.bmp');
$img->Write('k.jpg');
```

pp.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $l;
my @dll=glob "*.dll";
$l.=" -l $_" foreach(@dll);
print $l;
print `pp -v -o image.exe$l -M Image::Magick image.pl`;
```

Please tell me how to start the Imagemagick PAR
**== dll List ==**

```
-l analyze.dll -l atl100.dll -l CORE_RL_bzlib_.dll -l CORE_RL_coders_.dll -l CO
RE_RL_filters_.dll -l CORE_RL_jbig_.dll -l CORE_RL_jp2_.dll -l CORE_RL_jpeg_.dll
 -l CORE_RL_lcms_.dll -l CORE_RL_libxml_.dll -l CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll -l CORE_RL
_magick_.dll -l CORE_RL_png_.dll -l CORE_RL_tiff_.dll -l CORE_RL_ttf_.dll -l COR
E_RL_wand_.dll -l CORE_RL_xlib_.dll -l CORE_RL_zlib_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_aai_.dll -
l IM_MOD_RL_art_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_avs_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_bgr_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_bm
p_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_braille_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_cals_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_caption_.dl
l -l IM_MOD_RL_cin_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_cip_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_clip_.dll -l IM_MOD_R
L_clipboard_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_cmyk_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_cut_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_dcm_.
dll -l IM_MOD_RL_dds_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_debug_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_dib_.dll -l IM_MO
D_RL_djvu_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_dng_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_dot_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_dps_.dll
 -l IM_MOD_RL_dpx_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_emf_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_ept_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_
exr_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_fax_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_fd_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_fits_.dll -l IM
_MOD_RL_fpx_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_gif_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_gradient_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_g
ray_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_hald_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_hdr_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_histogram_.dl
l -l IM_MOD_RL_hrz_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_html_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_icon_.dll -l IM_MOD_
RL_info_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_inline_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_ipl_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_jbig_.d
ll -l IM_MOD_RL_jnx_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_jp2_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_jpeg_.dll -l IM_MOD_
RL_label_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_mac_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_magick_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_map_.d
ll -l IM_MOD_RL_mat_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_matte_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_meta_.dll -l IM_MO
D_RL_miff_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_mono_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_mpc_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_mpeg_.d
ll -l IM_MOD_RL_mpr_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_msl_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_mtv_.dll -l IM_MOD_R
L_mvg_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_null_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_otb_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_palm_.dll -
l IM_MOD_RL_pango_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pattern_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pcd_.dll -l IM_MOD
_RL_pcl_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pcx_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pdb_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pdf_.dll -
l IM_MOD_RL_pes_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pict_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pix_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_p
lasma_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_png_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pnm_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_preview_.dll
 -l IM_MOD_RL_ps2_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_ps3_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_ps_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_p
sd_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_pwp_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_raw_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_rgb_.dll -l IM_
MOD_RL_rla_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_rle_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_scr_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_sct_.dl
l -l IM_MOD_RL_sfw_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_sgi_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_stegano_.dll -l IM_MO
D_RL_sun_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_svg_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_tga_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_thumbnail
_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_tiff_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_tile_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_tim_.dll -l IM_
MOD_RL_ttf_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_txt_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_uil_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_url_.dl
l -l IM_MOD_RL_uyvy_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_vicar_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_vid_.dll -l IM_MOD
_RL_viff_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_wbmp_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_webp_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_wmf_.dl
l -l IM_MOD_RL_wpg_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_x_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_xbm_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_x
c_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_xcf_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_xpm_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_xps_.dll -l IM_M
OD_RL_xtrn_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_xwd_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_ycbcr_.dll -l IM_MOD_RL_yuv_.
dll -l mfc100.dll -l msvcp100.dll -l msvcr100.dll -l vcomp100.dll -l X11.dll -l
Xext.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you want is to have utility to convert from BMP to JPG?
In this case, I would recommend to simply get statically compiled version of ImageMagick **convert.exe** or GraphicsMagick **gm.exe** (you can get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick-binaries/1.2.5/GraphicsMagick-1.2.5-Q16-windows-static.exe/download)) and bundle it inside or next to your app.
Then you can call it as external utility as needed, and completely avoid these linking issues (I would consider this to be almost DLL hell).

**Edit**: explanation how to get static gm.exe to work. Download and install [GraphicsMagick-1.2.5-Q16-windows-static.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick-binaries/1.2.5/GraphicsMagick-1.2.5-Q16-windows-static.exe/download). After install is done, in its install directory find **gm.exe** and copy into your own directory (like your perl script). Now you can uninstall GraphicsMagick - **gm.exe** is all you need.

Now, when you need to convert BMP to JPG, simply call it like this:

```
 system("gm convert file.bmp file.jpg");
```

You should be able to also bundle gm.exe into your PAR file if you want.

Comment: ok Successful  miss dll folder  C:\Users\treeboa\Desktop\image\lib\auto\Image\Magick  dll change success    dont work C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\

Comment: I want to hide the process,
I do not want to use other processes

Comment: Do you realize that PAR extracts files it needs to run (like ImageMagick libs) into temporary directory? http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pp These files may even include source of your script! So you are not really buying anything. And you can easily add gm inside PAR, see here http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=805661